# Where to pass context data in Response (Django)

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, response

I am wondering how to pass some context data to response in Django.

I have this endpoint:

```
/api/facebook/user/
```

which returns data like this:

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {
        "facebook_account_id": "176890406129409",
        "first_name": "Ivan",
        "last_name": "K",
        "token_status": "active",
        "facebook_access_token": 1
    },
    {
        "facebook_account_id": "123123123",
        "first_name": "Ivan",
        "last_name": "FFFF",
        "token_status": null,
        "facebook_access_token": null
    },
    {
        "facebook_account_id": "123123",
        "first_name": "Test",
        "last_name": "test",
        "token_status": null,
        "facebook_access_token": null
    }
]
```

Here is my list serializer:

```
class FacebookUserListSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    token_status = SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = FacebookUser
        fields = ["facebook_account_id", "first_name", "last_name", "token_status", "facebook_access_token"]

    def get_token_status(self, obj):
        try:
            facebook_token = obj.facebook_access_token
            if facebook_token:
                return "active" if facebook_token.is_active else "inactive"
        except FacebookToken.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Here is my list view:

```
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    response = super().list(request, *args, **kwargs)
    data = response.data
    inactive_accounts = sum(1 for account in data if account.get("token_status") == "inactive")
    accounts_without_token = sum(1 for account in data if account.get("token_status") is None)
    context = {"inactive_accounts": inactive_accounts, "accounts_without_token": accounts_without_token} # Is this the correct way of passing context data to a response?
    response.context_data = context
    return response
```

In list view, in the "context" variable, I am attempting to pass data to the frontend, but I am sure that I am doing this incorrectly, I must first convert it to JSON, or make this somewhere else.

**So the question is - where (serializer, list method, or somewhere else?) and how should I put this *context* data according to REST conventions, so that data can be accessed in frontend without iterating over list items?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not loop through serialized data to find the information you want, use the view `queryset` instead. Also, there is no need to convert your response, DRF [`Response`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/responses/#responses) handles it automatically, given the correct `content-type`.

Since the extra information is not directly related to your object, doing it inside the `list` method is just fine. Else, you would use `get_serializer_context` method.

Here is a more "advanced" way on how to extract this information, using [`aggregation`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/aggregation/):

views.py

```
class FacebookUserList(ListAPIView):
    queryset = FacebookUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FacebookUserListSerializer

    def list(self, request):
        queryset = self.get_queryset()

        accounts_without_token = Q(facebook_access_token__isnull=True)
        inactive_accounts = (
            Q(facebook_access_token__is_active=False) | 
            Q(facebook_access_token__isnull=True)
        )

        metadata = queryset.aggregate(
            accounts_without_token=Count("pk", filter=accounts_without_token),
            inactive_accounts=Count("pk", filter=inactive_accounts),
        )

        serializer = self.get_serializer(
            queryset,
            many=True,
        )

        context = {
            "metadata": metadata,
            "users": serializer.data,
        }
        return Response(context)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation!